# Batch print a number of PDFs from a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, printing

I'm writing a quick one-off web application for a friend using Rails 3.0.9. It's a very simply organizational application that has the option to upload and store a PDF associated with an item. For example, the primary view of the application is a list:

- Group 1

  - Item 1 *(Link to PDF 1)*
  - Item 2 *(Link to PDF 2)*
- Group 2

  - Item 3 *(Link to PDF 3)*
  - Item 4 *(Link to PDF 4)*

This is all operational. PDFs are uploaded and stored in a directory: */railsapp/public/system/pdfs/*

One of the functional requirements of this application is to select any number of PDFs (checkboxes off to the side, or similar) and press a "Print All" button to initiate the printing of any number of them.

*For example, a user could select PDF 1, PDF 3, and PDF 4 then press "Print All" to print all of these PDFs in sequence.*

**Is there any way to accomplish this? It would also be acceptable to find a method/library that can be used in Rails to combine the selected PDFs, and print them "as one."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**pdftk**](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-cat) tool, the operation is **cat** (the one for which the link opens up). It would be something like this:

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf cat output 123.pdf
```

This will merge 1.pdf, 2.pdf and 3.pdf into 123.pdf.

Comment: works great. i used the 'exec' command in ruby to run the process, then added a link to the produced file.